# How can I flip all keyframes upside down in blender?

Tags: blender, modeling

In blender, I know there is a way to flip a group of keyframes by the x axis by copying and pasting (`ctrl+shift+v`) but how can I flip them upside down?

Comment: You can scale animation curves with S Y -1 (scale along Y axis -1 times), probably adjusting pivot point to origin first. The same can be done for X axis.

Comment: That... actually works! I didn't think of that originally... is there anyway you can form this comment into an answer so I can accept it as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move-rotate-scale operators can be used in 2D space too, so you can scale animation curves with `S` `Y` `-1` (scale along Y axis -1 times), probably adjusting pivot point to origin first (e.g. set pivot to "2d cursor" and set 2d cursor somewhere at Y=0. The same can be done for X axis.